# XBAP in fullscreen mode

Tags: wpf, fullscreen, xbap

I want to Run my XBAP in full screen mode. Is there any way to make IE to open XBAP in fullscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am running with full trust, whenever user clicks on full screen button, I used Process.Start() method to open IE in kiosk mode.

The following code solved my issue.

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "-k c:\MyXbap.xbap");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's any good way to do this, but you could set up a shortcut to open IE in Kiosk mode and fire up your xbap:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k c:\MyXbap.xbap
```

that would 'full screen' it.

Comment: this is something that we need to ask users to do it, but is there any way to do it programmatically, like we have full screen mode in silverlight or flash...